Linux Host Unit Testing Coverage - Not Generating .gcda file
I'm using version 5.0.2 of ESP-IDF.
I'm trying to get code coverage reports working for a custom component that I have existing unit tests for. I'm trying to set this up using ESP-IDF + CMake. I'm using ESP-IDFs nvs_flash component as an example.
I'm able to generate the .gcno files during compilation by adding the --coverage flag to the build process for both my test source file (file containing the unit tests) and the component under test source files. When I execute the resulting program (successfully), a .gcda file is only generated for the test source file but not for the source files in the component under test (functions for this are called from the test source file).
This is my current directory structure:
├── CMakeLists.txt (1)
├── component_file.c
├── component_file.h
├── host_test
 │   ├── component_unit_tests
 │   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt (2)
 │   │   ├── main
 │   │   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt (3)
 │   │   │   └── component_unit_tests.c
 │   │   └── sdkconfig.defaults

These are the contents of my CMakeLists.txt files:
// ---------- TOP LEVEL COMPONENT DIR ---------- //
// CMAKeLists.txt (1):

set(srcs "component_file.c")

set(include_dirs "...")

idf_component_register(SRCS "${srcs}"
                       INCLUDE_DIRS "${include_dirs}"
                       REQUIRES ...)

idf_build_get_property(target IDF_TARGET)
if(${target} STREQUAL "linux")
    target_compile_options(${COMPONENT_LIB} PUBLIC "-DLINUX_TARGET")
    target_compile_options(${COMPONENT_LIB} PUBLIC --coverage)
    target_link_libraries(${COMPONENT_LIB} PUBLIC --coverage)
endif()

// ---------- HOST TEST DIR ---------- //
// CMAKELISTS.txt (2):

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)

get_filename_component(REPO_DIR ${IDF_PATH} DIRECTORY)

set(COMPONENTS main)
list(APPEND EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS "${REPO_DIR}/components/") # Include Custom components

# Custom Component Mocks
...

# ESP-IDF Component Mocks
...

project(proj_name)

// CMakeLists.txt (3):

file(GLOB srcs "*.c")

get_filename_component(REPO_DIR ${IDF_PATH} DIRECTORY)

set(include_dirs "...")

idf_component_register(SRCS "${srcs}"
                       INCLUDE_DIRS "${include_dirs}"
                       REQUIRES unity cmock component_being_tested)

idf_build_set_property(COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-DCONFIG_UNITY_ENABLE_COLOR" APPEND)

target_compile_options(${COMPONENT_LIB} PUBLIC --coverage)
target_link_libraries(${COMPONENT_LIB} --coverage)



I made a comment in https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/13953, please let us know about the result there.
